# In windows 10 Search on Start menu doesn't list manually pinned executables, bug or user error?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, windows-search

If for example I pin the eclipse.exe to the start menu (the tiled section)(using context menu feature), and then search for it on the start menu (by typing the name) windows doesn't list that in the search result. I tried with other executables as well, no success. Is that my fault or a known bug?